# Changing child context object in SwiftUI View slow with onTapGesture

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a weird problem. I made a simple example to explore the problem.

For setup I have a Core Data Entity **SFSymbolNS** with one property **sfSymbol: String**.

```
@main
struct testiOS15App: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer
}
```

Now coming to the problem:

When creating a child Context and manipulating the String property the **onTapGesture** is **slower** when changing the property of the object **on the child context than** doing the same **on the parent context**.

Why is that?

**Here the structs for creation of the entity objects**:

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

//new symbol entity object with child context 
struct CreateOperation<Object: NSManagedObject>: Identifiable {    

    let id = UUID()
    let childContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    let object: Object
    
    init(withParentContext parentContext: NSManagedObjectContext) { 
        childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        childContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        childContext.parent = parentContext
        object = Object(context: childContext)
    }
}

//new symbol entity object with parent context
struct SFSymbol: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var sfSymbolObserved: SFSymbolNS
    let moc: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    init(parent: NSManagedObjectContext){
        moc = parent
        sfSymbolObserved = SFSymbolNS(context: moc)
    }
}
```

**Here are the Views**

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @State var symbolChild: CreateOperation<SFSymbolNS>?
    @State var symbolParent: SFSymbol?
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Button("child"){
                symbolChild = CreateOperation(withParentContext: moc)
            }
            .sheet(item: $symbolChild, content: {sf in
                SubView(sfSymbolObject: sf.object,label: ("slow","normal speed"))
            })

            Button("parent"){
                symbolParent = SFSymbol(parent: moc)
            }
            .sheet(item: $symbolParent, content: {sf in
                SubView(sfSymbolObject: sf.sfSymbolObserved,label: ("normal speed","normal speed"))
            })
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View{
    let symbolNames = ["creditcard.circle","creditcard","giftcard","cart.fill","bag","banknote","signature","person.2.fill","person.3.fill"]
    @ObservedObject var sfSymbolObject: SFSymbolNS
    let label: (String,String)
    var body: some View{
        SubSubView(sfSymbol: $sfSymbolObject.sfSymbol ?? "",label: label)
    }
}


struct SubSubView:View{
    @Binding var sfSymbol: String
    let label: (String,String)
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text("Change Symbol")
            Image(systemName: sfSymbol)
            Divider()
            Text(label.0)
            ForEach(["house","trash"],id:\.self){sf in
                Image(systemName: sf)
                    .background(sf == sfSymbol ? Color.green : Color.white)
                    .onTapGesture {     ---------------   //slow on child context
                        sfSymbol = sf
                    }
            }
            Divider().padding()
            Text(label.1)
            ForEach(["house","trash"],id:\.self){sf in
                Button(action: {     ---------------     //always fast
                    sfSymbol = sf
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: sf)
                        .background(sf == sfSymbol ? Color.green : Color.white)
                })
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// only for Parameter List

```
func ??<T>(lhs: Binding<Optional<T>>, rhs: T) -> Binding<T> {
    Binding(
        get: {
            lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs
        },
        set: {
            lhs.wrappedValue = $0
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you saving the child context? Try saving the child context so that the parent context picks up the change

Comment: I tried to save when creating the child, but it didn't help.

Comment: Provide the bare minimum code, isolate the bits so that everyone can focus on the problem area, so that we can try it. Always make an even comparison, one is a button and other is a tap gesture

Comment: Did you try it? It should be the minimum (or close to that). The button is necessary because the button shows that with the button the change is instant, while with the on tap gesture it is delayed.